# PrimeNG confirm dialog ignoring some properties like closeable or closeOnEscape

Tags: primeng

So here I have simple confirm dialog

```
                            <p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="fa fa-question-circle" width="425" closeable="false" closeOnEscape="false" #cd>
                                <p-footer>
                                    <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-close" label="No" (click)="cd.reject()"></button>
                                    <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-check" label="Yes" (click)="cd.accept()"></button>
                                </p-footer>
                            </p-confirmDialog>
```

however, for unknown to me reasons, dialog renders close button and closes on pressing esc key. Why `closeable` and `closeOnEscape` properties ignored? Only `width` and `hight` properties works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `closeable="false" closeOnEscape="false"` with `[closeable]="false" [closeOnEscape]="false"`

Comment: Y I have found that out already, but since cannot accept yet my answer, lets accept yours:) Can you tell me why widht/height properties works but not other ones?

Comment: because `width` and `height` are standard HTML attributes, while `closeOnEscape` and `closable` are PrimeNg/Angular custom attributes.